# @Viewchild throws undefined

Tags: angular

I have a component named SideToggleComponent having a function

```
 activeButton(value){
   ...
  }
```

I want to call this function to another component BlogComponent.
I am using @ViewChild like this

```
 @ViewChild( SideToggleComponent) private toggle: SideToggleComponent;
  startProject() {
      this.toggle.activeButton('');
    }
```

but it gives an error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'activeButton' of undefined.

Comment: Pleae share your html code

Comment: In my SideToggle component html   <button type="button" class="request-btn" (click)="activeButton('isActive1')">

Answer (score 0):

Viewchild works like this:

```
@ViewChild('fooComponent') fooComponent: FooComponent;
```

So lets split that up:

1.The string in @ViewChild('') is the reference in the template (which is declared with a #- symbol):

```
<foo-component #fooComponent></foo-component>
```

2.The 'fooComponent' afert the brackets is the name of the property

3.The FooComponent after the colon is the class- Name of the component

So finally your code should look like:

```
@ViewChild('sideToggleComponent') sideToggleComponent: SideToggleComponent;
startProject() {
  this.sideToggleComponent.activeButton('');
}
```

Comment: can you share the html of BlogComponent where you embed the SideToggleComponent component?

Answer (score 0):

**@ViewChild** is used to refer **Child Component** inside **Parent Component**.

You can use @ViewChild in **2 Ways**.

1. As @yannick suggested.
2. As you have written. **Your code do not have any issues.**

I think you are missing HTML part. You have not included selector of **SideToggleComponent** in **BlogComponent** HTML.

Both of the ways are correct.

@ViewChild will look for the reference of Child component inside Parent Component.

You have to make sure in **BlogComponent**, you have used **SideToggleComponent** in HTML like  or whatever **selector** you have defined for **SideToggleComponent**. You have to write this so that if will map your @ViewChild object with this component.

If you have written same in HTML, there might be loading sequence issue.